# Why will UIImageView not change to a different image having been set once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My code

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullResolutionImage]];
[_photoPreview setImage:img];
```

works fine for the first time. When I want to update the image in _photoPreview however, it will not do so and stays with the original.

I have a vague suspicion that this is to do with when the interface is loaded or something but I could be completely wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post some more code ?

Comment: Just put in a bit more. Don't really know which bits are useful to answers.

Comment: where is the code where you are changing the image ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `_photoPreview setNeedsDisplay`, so hat it just doesn't refresh it?

Comment: [_photoPreview setImage:img]; is the code. It is called more than once; it only works the first time.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Is the img you obtain the second time valid? Set a breakpoint and see if the img is valid actually.

Comment: Are you setting `_photoPreview` to `nil` at any point? Can you confirm that `_photoPreview` is not `nil` each time you call `setImage:`

Comment: Ahh, great ideas. I'll just check.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems changing the image in the image view by implementing the following code in a view controller.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)selectImage1:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
    [_imageView setImage:image1];
}

- (IBAction)selectImage2:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
    [_imageView setImage:image2];
}

- (IBAction)selectImage3:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];
    [_imageView setImage:image3];
}

@end
```